# Read and Write Excel file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

Is there any API or method to read and write Excel file in Javascript?I would like to know whether we can update 1000's of records in Excel in one row.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a language, JavaScript is technically capable of reading/writing data in any file format, however I haven't heard of any open plugins to read/write anything in particular other than zip files. In client-side JS this is largely unnecessary, but I could see the use for server-side JavaScript.

Comment: Actually our need is like if user enter cell and row values we need to read address from excel and display lat lon and save it to excel file.

Comment: In what environment?  That makes a big difference.  Technically you could just use JavaScript to automate Excel, but it's not clear from your question whether that would work for you.

Comment: How are you going to save to a file with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
function GetData() {
  var excel = new ActiveXObject(“Excel.Application”);
  var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open(“H: /sample_Codes/sample.xls”);
  var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets(“Sheet1″);
  var totalColCount = excel_sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
  var totalRowCount = excel_sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
  var htmlStr = ” < table > ”;
  for (i = 0; i < totalRowCount; i++) {
    htmlStr = htmlStr + “ < tr > ”;
    for (j = 0; j < totalColCount; j++)
      htmlStr = htmlStr + “ < td > ”+excel_sheet.Cells(i, j).Text + “ < /td>”;
htmlStr = htmlStr + “</tr > ”;
  }
  document.getElementById(‘ExcelContent’).innerHTML = htmlStr;
}
```

But this code requires Excel to be available in the client machine

Comment: Also requires that you're on a Windows machine too I'm assuming.

Answer (score -1):

Can you convert the spreadsheet to a CSV file and read that?