# how to overwrite data in html table and export this data to existed excel file

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel

I want to know how to export data in html table to existed excel file. I have found ways to export data to new excel file but what I want is to export this data to an existed excel file.
The code I found to export to new file but again I want to append this data to excel file that I already have.

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = 'scenario'){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer might interest  you https://stackoverflow.com/a/27490210/7942242 which

Comment: this answer is good for read, but I want it to write. I have my html table and I have an existed excel file so I want to overwrite my table data to my excel file